# Functions for an activity in a separate class

Tags: android, onclick, textwatcher

I have a MainMenuActivity with multiple fragments. I want to put my code for the fragment "Home" in a separate class. This is my current approach.

```
public class Home extends MainMenuActivity{

    public TextWatcher tw = new TextWatcher() {...};

    public Home(){

    }

    public void buttonPressed(View view){...}   
}
```

I want to add a TextWatcher to a EditText and functions which are executed, when a button is pressed
(defined in the xml: android:onClick="buttonPressed").

If this approach is possible, where and how can I create this class and should I put something in the Home constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Fragments in your project. Here are some examples :

- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

For your example you need to change MainMenuActivity to MainMenuFragmentActivity and create Home Fragment.

Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

With Java you shouldn't be afraid to have very large files (check `View.java` from the android source code, it's more than 15,000 lines long). There's no way to split a class like there is in C#.

But you say you use fragments. Why is your activity code so large? Usually most of the code go in the fragments, not in the activity.

Comment: Thank you for this awnser! I want to keep the files very small to get the code clear. And you are very right :D I am used to work with c#.

In the Activity there is the code to manage the fragments. Depending on the fragment i inflate a layout. 

I thought this Home class is my fragment? Sry I am new to this and may be I did something wrong.

Comment: You can extend `Fragment` and put all the code related to a fragment here (even click events). You should check the documentation : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html (This page may provide better examples : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

Comment: Thank you very much. The links are very helpful. But I have a problem with the onlick function. I created a button in the xml file which is inflated by the fragment. The Button should run the function buttonPressed(). Is it possible to place this function in the fragment?